# How to draw borders for System.Drawing.Region?

Tags: c#

I have `Region` that was created from two `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` objects using `Union()` method. How I can draw outline for this `Region`?

**Upd:**

I tried this:

```
        //Region RG = some region

        Pen P = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

        P.StartCap = P.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
        P.Width = 3;

        GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();

        GP.AddRectangles(RG.GetRegionScans(new Matrix()));

        g.DrawPath(P, GP);
        g.FillRegion(new SolidBrush(fillColor), RG);
```

But I think that this is not correct.

Comment: You can draw the GraphicsPath, can't you? You can use AddPath instead of union and draw the reuslting path.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @TaW somewhere I need to use `Intersect()` method, that's why I cant use `GraphicsPath`.

Comment: @MikeC yep, I tried to search it in Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution for this problem:

```
    //Region RG = some region

    Pen P = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

    P.StartCap = P.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
    P.Width = 3;

    GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();

    GP.AddRectangles(RG.GetRegionScans(new Matrix()));

    g.DrawPath(P, GP);
    g.FillRegion(new SolidBrush(fillColor), RG);
```